# Update entry(existing row) in microsoft azure database through android application

Tags: android, azure, ssms, azure-sql-database

I am making an android application with database connectivity through Microsoft Azure. I have successfully created table in Azure and connected it to my application.I have used SQL management studio(2014) for creating Database. I am also able to enter data to the table by my application, according to the methods specified in Microsoft Azure mobile services, but I am facing problem in updating my database. I entered information to my database at one point in the app. At later stage I need to enter data to other columns corresponding to the previous entry (i.e updating existing row), which I am not able to do. The solutions available are not helping me to obtain my goal. Please tell me the exact code(java) which I need to write in my android application or procedure which I should follow to update properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following code shows how to update data in a table. In this example, `item` is a reference to a row in the `ToDoItem` table, which has had some changes made to it. The following method updates the table and the `UI adapter`.

```
private void updateItem(final ToDoItem item) {
    if (mClient == null) {
        return;
    }

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                mToDoTable.update(item).get();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if (item.isComplete()) {
                            mAdapter.remove(item);
                        }
                        refreshItemsFromTable();
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                createAndShowDialog(exception, "Error");
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

**For further queries visit :**https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-how-to-use-client-library/#updating